# Percentage of a conformer in vacuum

Tags: molecules, conformers

I just started with Molecular dynamics simulations. My background is computer science but I'm learning about scientific computing and thus my jump into MD.

Having said that, I was asked to calculate the percentage of each conformer in vacuum at a certain temperature of the Methylcyclohexane molecule. Assuming that entropies and molar volumes are identical.

Can someone point me out to some website or something where I can see how to calculate this?

Answer (score 8):

Page 11699 of [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja011357l) has one approach to what you want: basically, you compute the relative Gibbs free energies of the possible stable conformers, assume they can interconvert, and use a Boltzmann distribution to work out what the percentages are.

> First, we selected a reference structure $R$ for a given species (neutral or protonated).
>
> Next, for every structure $M$ other than the reference structure $R$ we determined the
>   equilibrium constant $K_M$ $$K_M = \frac{[M]}{[R]}$$ from the difference in Gibbs free energies for $M$ and $R$. The fraction of $M$ in the equilibrated sample is given by:
>
> $$x_M = K_M/\left(1 + K_1 + K_2 + ...\right)$$
>
> where the sum in the denominator goes through all structures for a
>   given species. The fraction of $R$ in the sample is:
>
> $$x_R = 1/\left(1 + K_1 + K_2 + ...\right)$$

They don't include it in the paper, but the way to calculate an equilibrium constant $K$ from a difference in Gibbs free energy $\Delta G$ is:

$$ \Delta G = RT \ln K $$

where $R$ is the [molar gas constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant), and $T$ is the temperature (in Kelvin).

The tricky part is then working out what your stable conformers are, generally using some form of either guesswork or conformation sampling algorithm. They use a genetic algorithm of some sort in the paper I linked to, but given that methylcyclohexane isn't that complex a molecule, you might want to just take a look at an [energy diagram and discussion of conformers of cyclohexane](http://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=7926) for some hints.

If you're getting deep into molecular dynamics, you could also use some sort of algorithm designed to use dynamic simulation to sample a wide area on a potential surface, like metadynamics or umbrella sampling, to find your conformers, and probably calculate your free energies at the same time.

You can use a static method to calculate the free energies instead, though -- the method you use to do this will depend on what sort of accuracy you're after, and may vary from a classical forcefield technique through Density Functional Theory to coupled-cluster theory (in ascending order of computational expense).